# usar dato de ciclo while en una consulta fuera del ciclo

Tags: php, mysql, while

hola a todos es un tanto comprejo el titulo perdon,

en si lo que quiero es utilizar un dato que consigo de una consulta de un siclo while en otra consulta que estoy realizando dentro del mismo documento php

este es mi ciclo while

```html
              <?php
              $_proceso = $_GET['var'];
              $query = "SELECT id,Nombre_proceso FROM proceso WHERE Nombre_proceso = '$_proceso'";
                $_result = $conn->query($query);
                if (!$_result) die($conn->error); 
                
                while ($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_result)){
                    $_proceso = $_row["Nombre_proceso"];
                    $_id = $_row["id"];
                        }
              ?>
```

esta es la parte donde quiero utilizar el dato ID que saque del siclo while

```html
<?php
                            $query = "SELECT riesgo,Criticidad,Ocurrencia,Reaccion,Valor,CASE
                                        WHEN Decision = 0 THEN 'Eliminar'
                                        WHEN Decision = 1 THEN 'Mitigar'
                                        WHEN Decision = 2 THEN 'Delegar'
                                        WHEN Decision = 3 THEN 'Aceptar'
                                        END as Decision,Plan_Accion FROM riesgo_metodo_que where id_Proceso = ".$_id = row['id']."  Order By Valor";
                            $result = $conn->query($query);
                            if (!$result) die($conn->error);
                        ?>
```

Comment: `where id_Proceso = ".$_id."  Order By Valor";`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _id

Answer (score 0):

podrías colocar la query en una funcion que se llame con cada interacción, algo así:

```
$_proceso = $_GET['var'];
$query = "SELECT id,Nombre_proceso FROM proceso WHERE Nombre_proceso = '$_proceso'";
$_result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$_result) die($conn->error); 

$respuesta = "";

while ($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_result)){
    $_proceso = $_row["Nombre_proceso"];
    $_id = $_row["id"];
    $respuesta = getDatos([$_id,$conn]);
    break;
}

function getDatos($x){
    $query = "SELECT riesgo,Criticidad,Ocurrencia,Reaccion,Valor,CASE
                WHEN Decision = 0 THEN 'Eliminar'
                WHEN Decision = 1 THEN 'Mitigar'
                WHEN Decision = 2 THEN 'Delegar'
                WHEN Decision = 3 THEN 'Aceptar'
                END as Decision,Plan_Accion FROM riesgo_metodo_que where id_Proceso = ".$x[0]."  Order By Valor";
    $result = $x[1]->query($query);
    if (!$result) die($x[1]->error);

    return $result;
}

var_dump($respuesta);
```

Prueba así a ver. Saludos

Comment: me manda error Notice: Undefined variable: conn y Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on nul

Comment: @antoniosanchez ya edite mi respuesta, como vez, ahora le paso la variable de conexión a la función para que ejecute la query, prueba y avias. Saludos